# Extending a protocol to provide default compliance to "Comparable" protocol

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols

I would like to have a default implementation of `Comparable` for a protocol I declare. The following gives the error `Extension of protocol 'Asset' can not have an inheritance clause`

```
protocol Asset {
    func getPriority() -> AssetPriority
}

extension Asset: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Asset, rhs: Asset) -> Bool {
        return lhs.getPriority() < rhs.getPriority()
    }
    static func == (lhs: Asset, rhs: Asset) -> Bool {
        return lhs.getPriority() == rhs.getPriority()
    }
}
```

I know I can do protocol inheritance (without the extension):

```
protocol Asset: Comparable {
    func getPriority() -> AssetPriority
}
```

but then I have to implement the same two functions over and over again.

I don't want every asset to inherit from a common base class (since that defeats the purpose of protocols...)

Is protocol extension of a protocol just not supported yet in Swift 3 (like it is for classes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protocol must inherit from `Comparable` in its main declaration. You can then add a default implementation of `Comparable`'s methods in an extension.

```
protocol Asset: Comparable {
    func getPriority() -> AssetPriority
}

extension Asset {
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.getPriority() < rhs.getPriority()
    }
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.getPriority() == rhs.getPriority()
    }
}
```

Comment: @DudeOnRock Compiles just fine: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/587abe5eaadcf805dca39a23

Comment: @DudeOnRock But yeah, `Asset` can't be used as it's own type anymore if you inherit from `Equatable` or `Comparable`. It's an incomplete type

Comment: Sorry, I judged your answer too quickly... I had `Asset` instead of `Self` for the argument types in the extension. Thank you so much!